# Crash Log TTBaseNavigator - Assistance Requested

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

The App review board sent my app back to me due to it crashing for them (I cannot reproduce the crash). I symbolicated the log and am including it here below, want to make sure I am reading it correctly ( first time trying to decipher a crash log ).

If I am reading it right the crash occurs at line 712 in TTBaseNavigator.m -- which is called from this line in my project:

[navigator openURLAction:[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:@"strangeware://main"]];

The app works without crashing in the simulator and on my iPhone 3G (using latest OS 4.2.1) it also never crashes, but Apple reports that on their iPhone 4 with OS 4.3 it crashes consistently.

Am wondering if I am reading the log correctly and if so am looking for advice on how to proceed, given I cannot reproduce the error either in the simulator or on my iPhone device.

Thanks for any assistance,
Andy

```
     Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    Thread 0 Crashed:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00011a1c __pthread_kill + 8
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000333b4 pthread_kill + 52
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0002bbf8 abort + 72
    3   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00044a64 __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() + 376
    4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000606c _objc_terminate + 104
    5   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00042e36 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 46
    6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00042e8a std::terminate() + 10
    7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00042f5a __cxa_throw + 78
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00004c84 objc_exception_throw + 64
    9   CoreFoundation                  0x000a21b8 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 96
    10  CoreFoundation                  0x000a1642 ___forwarding___ + 502
    11  CoreFoundation                  0x00018178 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 40
    12  ImageGallery                    0x00040654 -[TTBaseNavigator viewControllerForURL:query:pattern:] (TTBaseNavigator.m:712)
    13  ImageGallery                    0x0003f6c2 -[TTBaseNavigator openURLAction:] (TTBaseNavigator.m:502)
    14  ImageGallery                    0x0000247e -[ImageGalleryAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] (ImageGalleryAppDelegate.m:36)
    15  UIKit                           0x0003581a -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 766
    16  UIKit                           0x0002fb5e -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 266
    17  UIKit                           0x000047d0 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1108
    18  UIKit                           0x0000420e -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 38
    19  UIKit                           0x00003c4c _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5084
    20  GraphicsServices                0x00004e70 PurpleEventCallback + 660
    21  CoreFoundation                  0x00075a90 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
    22  CoreFoundation                  0x00077838 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 160
    23  CoreFoundation                  0x00078606 __CFRunLoopRun + 514
    24  CoreFoundation                  0x00008ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
    25  CoreFoundation                  0x00008dc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
    26  UIKit                           0x0002ed42 -[UIApplication _run] + 366
    27  UIKit                           0x0002c800 UIApplicationMain + 664
    28  ImageGallery                    0x00002336 main (main.m:15)
    29  ImageGallery                    0x00002300 start + 32

    Thread 1:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000123ec __workq_kernreturn + 8
    1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000346d8 _pthread_wqthread + 592
    2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00034bbc start_wqthread + 0

    Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
    Thread 2:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00012fbc kevent + 24
    1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00006094 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 672
    2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000704a _dispatch_queue_invoke + 86
    3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000660a _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 190
    4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0003458a _pthread_wqthread + 258
    5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00034bbc start_wqthread + 0

    Thread 3 name:  WebThread
    Thread 3:
    0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000fc00 mach_msg_trap + 20
    1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000f758 mach_msg + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                  0x000762b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
    3   CoreFoundation                  0x00078562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
    4   CoreFoundation                  0x00008ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
    5   CoreFoundation                  0x00008dc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
    6   WebCore                         0x0000637a RunWebThread(void*) + 378
    7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0003330a _pthread_start + 242
    8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00034bb4 thread_start + 0

    Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
        r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
        r4: 0x3f8d148c    r5: 0x00000006      r6: 0x0013ed6c      r7: 0x2fdfe0fc
        r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x0013e4b0     r11: 0x00000000
        ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdfe0f0      lr: 0x367203bb      pc: 0x31203a1c
      cpsr: 0x00000010
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of three20 are you using? Did you make sure you have the linker flags set correctly? originalNavigatorURL is a category method on UIViewController. In earlier versions of three20 you needed to have the linker flags -all_load -ObjC. It's possible your Distribution build does not have these flags set.

Comment: I do have those linker flags set. Thanks.